# Which O/R Mappers (.NET) support polymorphic queries?

Tags: .net, orm, polymorphism

I know NHibernate supports Polymorphic queries. The classic sample

```
from System.Object
```

will return all objects in the database.

Which **other** mappers support such types of queries?

LINQ2SQL definitely not. Genome (that's a good one too) also not.
I'm not sure with Entity Framework.

This is a 100% must-have feature for a business application framework I'm currently planning. But I'm not so in favour for NHibernate because I had bad performance experiences with large domain models (> 250 Entities) some years ago (1.1. Version)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Telerik OpenAccess ORM](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx). It's free for MS Sql Server.